# Why my VHDL code for generating a VGA signal doesn't work

Tags: vhdl, clock, xilinx, vga, spartan

I have been going crazy trying to make it work but nothing been on this for the past 6 hours and still didn't solve it :/

so this the top module

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity Test is
  Port ( CLKI : in  STD_LOGIC;
         HSO : out  STD_LOGIC;
         VSO : out  STD_LOGIC;
         RO,GO,BO : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Test;

architecture Behavioral of Test is
  component CLK_25Mhz_Divider
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           CLK_OUT : out  STD_LOGIC);
  end component;

  component VGA_Sync
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           HS : out  STD_LOGIC;
           VS : out  STD_LOGIC;
           R,G,B : out  STD_LOGIC);
  end component;

  signal CLKBE: STD_LOGIC;

begin

  CLK_Divider_1: CLK_25Mhz_Divider port map ( CLK => CLKI,
                                              CLK_OUT => CLKBE);

  VGA_S1: VGA_Sync port map ( CLK => CLKBE,
           HS => HSO,
           VS => VSO,
           R  => RO,
              G  => GO,
              B  => BO );

end Behavioral;
```

the clock divider

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity CLK_25MHz_Divider is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           CLK_OUT : out  STD_LOGIC);
end CLK_25MHz_Divider;

architecture Behavioral of CLK_25MHz_Divider is

 BEGIN
     PROCESS(CLK)
          VARIABLE COUNT : INTEGER:=0;
          VARIABLE TEMP : STD_LOGIC:='0';
          BEGIN
                IF RISING_EDGE(CLK)THEN
                     COUNT:=COUNT+1;
                     IF COUNT=2 THEN
                          TEMP:=NOT TEMP;
                          COUNT:=0;
                     END IF;
                END IF;
                CLK_OUT<=TEMP;
                END PROCESS;
end Behavioral;
```

The VGA signal generation module

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity VGA_Sync is
    Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           HS : out  STD_LOGIC;
           VS : out  STD_LOGIC;
           R,G,B : out STD_LOGIC);
end VGA_Sync;

architecture Behavioral of VGA_Sync is

begin 

  process(CLK)

  Variable countH : Integer := 0;
  Variable countV : Integer := 0;

    begin
     if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then

        if countH < 800 then 
            countH := countH + 1;
        else 
            countH := 0;
           if countV < 500 then
                countV := countV + 1;
        else 
               countV := 0;
           end if;
        end if;

        if countH >= 16 and countH < 112 then
           HS <= '0';
       else 
           HS <= '1';
        end if;

        if countV >= 10 and countV < 12 then
           VS <= '0';
       else 
           VS <= '1';
        end if;

        if (countH < 160) or (countV < 45) then 
           R <= '0';
            G <= '0';
            B <= '0';
        else 
           R <= '1';
            G <= '0';
            B <= '1';
      end if;
   end if;
 end process;       
end Behavioral;
```

so tell me your thoughts on what is wrong with the code

Comment: Btw the resolution i am aiming for is 640x480

Comment: Please cleanup your question. You have posted `vga_sync` two times. A top-level component as well as a testbench is missing. And what is the error (message)? And remove unneccessary comment lines.

Comment: sorry about posting vga_sync twice i fixed it now. it's not that i get an error my code gives me no syntax errors but when i connect the board to a screen nothing shows up when the pixels' color should change to magenta. i've done a test bench but it's not worth writing here since it's only a Clock in and the test bench didn't show anything wrong, i could include it with some screen shots of the wave form if you want to.

Comment: What is the frequency of `CLKI`? That's why I asked for a testbench.

Comment: at that resolution i should use 25Mhz so i using the onboard clock that's 50 Mhz and dividing it using the Clock divider module.

Comment: Did it work in the simulator? Where is the testbench?

Comment: Describe the problem. This question is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't actually describe the problem and because I had a testbench for a 25 MHz clocked vga generator that only required changing the type for r, g and b, I ran you sync_vga against the testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity vga_sync_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of vga_sync_tb is
    signal clk:    std_logic := '0';
    signal hs:     std_logic;
    signal vs:     std_logic;
    signal r,g,b:  std_logic;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.vga_sync 
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            hs => hs,
            vs => vs,
            r => r,
            g => g,
            b => b
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;  -- clock period 25 MHz = 40 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 20 ms then  -- one frame time plus a bit
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

It gave a vertical sync rate around  60 Hz:

[image: sync_vga_tb_full.png]

Zooming in and measuring between two HS edges shows a horizontal rate of around 31.17 KHz.

You have horizontal and vertical blanking intervals and your R, G, and B does what your code says.

That sort of leaves the clock divider or something platform related.

Because a testbench for the clock is simple:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity clock_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of clock_tb is
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal clk25:   std_logic;
begin
DUT:
    entity work.clk_25mhz_divider
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            clk_out => clk25
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns; -- half the period of 50 MHz
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 130 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

It demonstrates Martin Zabel's answer:

[image: clock_tb.png]

That your divide by two actually divides by four. giving a period of 80 ns (12.5 MHz).

This demonstrates the usefulness of simulation and in simulation it can also be helpful to use signals instead of variables which have no history. Variables don't have a projected output waveform and he simulator has to attach extra code to display them in a waveform.

The simulation performance increase using variables instead of signals is traded for the ability to display them and there is no interesting distinction in synthesis.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. it's something that i would keep in mind in the future. I am not well versed in VHDL as i  don't use it often but i am getting the hang of it.

Comment: @Mostafa : if you learn one thing from this excellent answer, let it be this : it doesn't take six hours to write a testbench and simulate your design.

Comment: I have to admit, that this answer is better than mine because it demonstrates sub-module testing. So, +1. Too bad, I should have know this.

Answer (score 0):

From comments below question:

> at that resolution i should use 25Mhz so i using the onboard clock
>   that's 50 Mhz and dividing it using the Clock divider module. –
>   Mostafa

Your clock divider divides the input frequency by 4 instead of 2. You toggle `TEMP` every two cycles of `CLK` which is `CLKI` of the top module. So a full cycle of `CLK_OUT` takes 4 cycles of the input clock.

To divide by two, you must toggle `TEMP` every clock cycle of the input clock:

```
architecture Behavioral of CLK_25MHz_Divider is
BEGIN
     PROCESS(CLK)
          VARIABLE TEMP : STD_LOGIC:='0';
     BEGIN
         IF RISING_EDGE(CLK)THEN
             TEMP:=NOT TEMP;
         END IF;
         CLK_OUT<=TEMP;
     END PROCESS;

end Behavioral;
```

Starting with `TEMP = '0'`, it toggles to '1' at the first rising edge of `CLK`. At the second rising edge, `TEMP` toggles to '0', and at the third rising edge back to '1'. The duration between the first and third rising-edge of the 50 MHz input clock is 40 ns, which makes a frequency of 25 MHz for the output clock.